# Using variables to access object property in blade file of laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, object, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Given the following PHP object and variable

```
$options = { 'options' : { '0' : 'Off' , '1' : 'On' }}
$data->{$row->field}} = 0 or 1
```

**Syntax error method**

Why am I not able to access the '0' and '1' property of the`$options->options` object by calling the property through an object variable directly such as in the form of`<span class="label label-info"> {{ $options->options->{$data->{$row->field}} }}`. This will result in the error "*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'*"

**Workaround solution 1**

However, it would work if I create an intermediate variable to store `$data->{$row->field};` before calling the property via the intermediate variable from the object

```
@php
    $enable_company_logo_white_label =  $data->{$row->field};
@endphp
            
{{-- Working Code --}}
<span class="label label-info"> {{ $options->options->{$enable_company_logo_white_label} }}</span>
```

**Workaround solution 2**

Another workaround is to call `{!! $options->options->{$data->{$row->field}} !!}` without escaping special characters

***Why does the first method result in syntax error whereas the 2 workaround solution works?***

Comment: I would guess it's because `}}` gets replaced to `);?>` by blade as in `{{ $something }}` in blade is `<?php echo e($something); ?>`. Does using `<?= $options->options->{$data->{$row->field}}; ?>` work?

Answer (score -1):

So I am pretty sure this might be mentioned somewhere on Stackoverflow or documentation. But I can still try.

 **Syntax error method**

Blade templating engine is designed to be default secure, so it escapes output by default to prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks. So when you try to access the nested property using `$options->options->{$data->{$row->field}}`, Blade may interpret it incorrectly, leading to a syntax error.

**Workaround solution 1**

By assigning the result of `$data->{$row->field}` to an intermediate variable, you break down the operation into multiple steps allowing Blade to interpret it correctly because it can handle the intermediate variable without confusion.

**Workaround solution 2**

You using the `{!! !!}` syntax, which outputs the content as it is without escaping special characters. Although this works but has security issues if the content isn't properly sanitized or trusted as it bypasses Laravel's default escaping mechanisms. (Not usually recommended if you are dealing with user generated content or content that may contain potentially harmful input).